# I can't understand this sentence with "es ging mir"

Tags: sentence-structure, german-to-english

The following sentence is taken from the introduction of the book *Der Besuch der alten Dame*, which I'm trying to read.

> Es ging mir, im Gegensatz zu den verschiedenen Fassungen, die vorher einzeln im Arche-Verlag erschienen sind, bei den Fassungen fuer die Werkausgabe nicht darum, die theatergerechten, das heisst die gestrichenen Fassungen herauszugeben, sondern die literarisch gueltigen.

I interpret the first two parts of the sentence as: "I feel that, in contrast to the other editions, which are exclusively published by Arche before, …" But I'm lost then, since I don't understand the overall structure of the sentence.

My specific concern is that normally I would expect a prepositional phrase followed by an adjective after "es ging mir" like in sentences such as "es geht mir in den letzten zwei Wochen gut". Therefore I don't quite understand the structure of this sentence.

Comment: Leaving out the parentheses, the sentence reads "Es ging mir ... nicht darum, die theatergerechten ... Fassungen herauszugeben, sondern die literarisch gültigen (Fassungen)." The point was not to publish the editions suitable for theatrical performance, but the literary valid ones.

Comment: "Einzeln" here does not mean "exclusively", but "individually".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Es geht mir darum

translates to "my concern is" or "my intention is"

The core sentence is

> Es ging mir nicht darum, die theatergerechten, sondern die literarisch gültigen Fassungen herauszugeben

the rest is embellishment.

So the core sentence translates to

> My intention was not to provide the editions adapted for stage, but the literary valid

The various parenthesises around the core sentence you should be able to put into the right places yourself.

Answer (score 5):

This is a very complicated sentence, and even I as German native had to read it a few times to understand it.

This is the basic structure of the sentence (as I understand it):

> Es ging mir, [...], bei den Fassungen fuer die Werkausgabe nicht darum, die theatergerechten, [...] herauszugeben, sondern die literarisch gueltigen.

The two parenthesis:

1.

> im Gegensatz zu den verschiedenen Fassungen, die vorher einzeln im Arche-Verlag erschienen sind

Your already translated this one correct.

2.

> das heisst die gestrichenen Fassungen

This relates to the previous word "theatergerecht" (made to be performed in a theater)

Comment: Ich würde noch darauf hinweisen, dass "einzeln" missverstanden wurde. Gute und übersichtliche Strukturierung!